# Conversion failed when converting the "invalid" value 'Residential' to data type int

Tags: java, sql, scenebuilder

How do I convert data that is given from result set string.
I am trying to show the drop down box gui as a text but give it a value of 1 and 2

what I want it to show as for drop down choice is right:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMhBr.png

but I need the actual values to be 1 and 2 correspondingly

Then I need to put those values back into a database f key that only allows int...

```
final ObservableList options = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


public void fillComboBox() {
    Connection c;


    try {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        String queryx = "Select CusType_ID, CusTypeName from CustomerType";

        ResultSet jrs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(queryx);

        while (jrs.next()) {

            String custyID = jrs.getString("CusType_ID");
            String custyN = jrs.getString("CusTypeName");


            options.add(new MyObject(custyID,custyN));
            typeBox.setItems(options);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



String sql = "INSERT INTO Customer [CustomerType_ID]) VALUES" typeBox.getValue() +"')";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a class for storing the CusType_ID and CusTypeName in dropdown(combobox)

```
public class MyObject {

private String key;
private String value;

public MyObject(String key, String value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.text = value;
}

public String getKey(){
return key ;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

then store the value from your request

```
     String queryx = "Select CusType_ID, CusTypeName from CustomerType";

    ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(queryx);

    while (rs.next()) {
        int recordNumber = 1;
        int recNumber =2;

        String sx = rs.getString("CusTypeName");
        String customerID = rs.getString("CusType_ID");


        typeBox.addItem(new MyObject(customerID, sx));


        }
```

Finally, get your value back from selected item and store it in your new sql

```
Object item = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
String value = ((MyObject)item).getKey();
String sql = "INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerType_ID) VALUES ("+ 
value +");" ;
```

Comment: I don't know why I am getting this error. ChoiceBox$ChoiceBoxSelectionModel cannot be cast to sample.MyObject, my comboBox is named typeBox

Comment: i Updated my code so you could better understand it, I also made that separate class like you made.

Comment: nvm I GOT IT. thank you so much. for some reason my call is different for the selection. It had to be  Object item = typeBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, did it worked? , if not it might you didn't choose the selected item    --> String sql = "INSERT INTO Customer [CustomerType_ID]) VALUES" typeBox.getSelectedItem().getValue() +"')";  , please let me know if you want any think else